# Java: Enerjy - Unchecked Exception?

Tags: java

Enerjy has a problem with this line of code:

```
private static List<ParseTree> getTestTrees(Xml test) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
```

This is the warning:

```
(Baseline) JAVA0126 Method 'getTestTrees' declares unchecked exception 'IllegalArgumentException' in throws
```

How can I fix this? What is the problem? What does it mean for an exception to be "unchecked"?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that just a warning, not an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unchecked" exceptions (also known as [runtime exceptions](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)) are those that the compiler does not force you to catch. For example, imagine if you had to declare and catch `NullPointerException` everywhere it might occur. These are the types of exceptions that, if they occur, the assumption is your program likely can't recover anyway.

The compiler is telling you to remove `IllegalArgumentException` from the `throws` clause of your method.